# MVC 2 RenderAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im having a value in ViewData, lets say htmlhelper.ViewData["myData"]="some";

And in partial page I can overwrite the myData's value.

But when I using the Html.RenderAction() and call a partial page.

In the same partial page htmlhelper.ViewData["myData"] is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out from MVC source code. Cool that we have MVC as open source.

```
htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["myData"]
```

this will maintain the value from Partial and RenderAction case.

Answer (score 3):

When you call RenderAction, you create an entirely new ViewData instance for your partial page.  If you want ViewData["myData"] to be visible by your other action, either pass it to the subaction or put it in TempData.

Comment: how to pass it to the subaction ?

Comment: The same as if you were calling another action from the view ... Something like:

Html.RenderAction("SomeAction", 
  new { id = 1, param2 = "something, param3 = "something else" })